# Hydration error caused my code to stop working entirely for Header component on next.js

Tags: next.js

```
import React from "react";
import { SocialIcon } from "react-social-icons";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Link from "next/link";

type Props = {};

export default function Header({}: Props) {
  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 p-5 flex items-start justify-between max-w-7xl mx-auto z-20 xl:items-center">
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          x: -500,
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 0.5,
        }}
        animate={{
          x: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 1.5,
        }}
        className="flex flex-row items-center"
      >
        {/*Social Icons*/}
        <SocialIcon
          className="hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          url="https://github.com/manavparmar04"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />

        <SocialIcon
          className="hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          url="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mr+beast"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />
        <SocialIcon
          className="hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          url="https://www.instagram.com/manav.04/"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />
        <SocialIcon
          className="hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/manav-parmar-039a24248/"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />
      
      </motion.div>

        <Link href="#contact">
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          x: 500,
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 0.5,
        }}
        animate={{
          x: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 1.5,
        }}
        className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
      >
        <SocialIcon
          className="cursor-pointer hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          network="email"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />
        <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400 hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200">
          Get in touch
        </p>
      </motion.div>
      </Link>
    </header>
  );
}
```

```
<Link href="#contact">
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          x: 500,
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 0.5,
        }}
        animate={{
          x: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 1.5,
        }}
        className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
      >
        <SocialIcon
          className="cursor-pointer hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200"
          network="email"
          fgColor="gray"
          bgColor="transparent"
          target="_blank"
        />
        <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400 hover:opacity-40 opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-200">
          Get in touch
        </p>
      </motion.div>
      </Link>`
```

Entire code ^`

Where the issue started^

With the issue code above I kept running into an hyrdration error, the more i tried to debug the more it kept happening and eventually the entirety of my header component didn't react to any new code added or any code i deleted. Even if i had more social icons or different types of animations or even deleting social icons, nothing changes on my website after refreshing/ saving the code.

I tried to restart my laptop several times, tried running "yarn run dev" multiple times as well in hopes of it working but nothing seems to be working. I'd really appreciate help on this as this is also my first time working with next.js.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I fixed this issue because i had a file called header1.tsx which was linked to my index.tsx instead of header.tsx. I only realized this after duplicating my file.